# Dependency property as a Target for the binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I define a dependency property in one of my classes. Can I use that dependency property to act as a target of Binding? If yes, how do I do that in code?

Comment: Just like you would with any other property.

Comment: Thanks svick. I was not able to figure out the way to do it. I Thought only classes deriving from FrameworkElement would do this by calling its SetBinding method. But it can be done using  BindingOpeations.SetBinding(dependencyObject, dp,binding).Thanks again.

Comment: Dependecy properties work on all classes that derive from `DependencyObject`, it doesn't have to be `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: Svick, Are there other ways of setting binding in code other than these :
1. FrameworkElement.SetBinding(..) 
2. BindingOpeations.SetBinding(...)

Answer (score 2):

ONLY dependency properties can be `Target` of `Binding` in WPF. Source of the binding can be any CLR object. Dependency properties are exhibited by dependency objects.

E.g.

```
   var binding = new Binding("EmployeeName");
   myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

The code above binds `EmployeeName` from the data context to myTextBlock's `Text` property.